# Split string in Lua, save in 2 variables

Tags: string, lua, split, division

I have one string, that is = `s = "Pedro Martinez, Defense"`

I want to split the string before the comma and after the comma, store those cuts on 2 variables, for example:

I think that I need to use the `string.gmatch` function or `string.sub`

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The accepted answer at [How to convert GPS coordinates to decimal in Lua?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19085239/how-to-convert-gps-coordinates-to-decimal-in-lua/19466325#19466325) shows how to use string.match and patterns. Applying the same techniques as mentioned there, you could use

```
local name, expertise = string.match(s, "(.*),%s*(%a*)")
```

which would lead to name being "Pedro Martinez" and expertise being "Defense".

Comment: I'd use `.*` instead of `%a*` for consistency.

Comment: Yes, it is probably safer too since (%a*) will end capture at first non-letter (digit, punctuation, etc).