# Timestamp pattern

Tags: lua, timestamp, coronasdk

Let's assume I have the following reminder timestamp

```
local reminder_timestamp = "2013-12-13T00:00:00+01:00"
```

And I'm using the below function to return time in UTC

```
local function makeTimeStamp(dateString)
      local pattern = "(%d+)%-(%d+)%-(%d+)%a(%d+)%:(%d+)%:([%d%.]+)([Z%p])(%d%d)%:?(%d%d)"
      local year, month, day, hour, minute, seconds, tzoffset, offsethour, offsetmin = dateString:match(pattern)
      local timestamp = os.time( {year=year, month=month, day=day, hour=hour, min=minute, sec=seconds} )
      local offset = 0
      if ( tzoffset ) then
        if ( tzoffset == "+" or tzoffset == "-" ) then  -- we have a timezone!
          offset = offsethour * 60 + offsetmin
          if ( tzoffset == "-" ) then
            offset = offset * -1
          end
          timestamp = timestamp + offset

        end
      end
  return timestamp
end
```

What should be the pattern above to match the reminder timestamp I mentioned earlier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer and the function actually works fine

```
pattern = "(%d+)%-(%d+)%-(%d+)%a(%d+)%:(%d+)%:([%d%.]+)([Z%p])(%d%d)%:?(%d%d)"

reminder_timestamp = "2013-12-23T08:00:00+01:00"

local year, month, day, hour, minute, seconds, tzoffset, offsethour, offsetmin = reminder_timestamp:match(pattern)
```

Resource: http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#5.4.1

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Lua's string parsing capabilities. Try a few of the techniques mentioned in the following, and if you still have issues, post specifically what is not working:

- [Question about splitting string and saving in several variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20180258/split-string-in-lua-save-in-2-variables)
- [Question about extracting data from a string, very similar to yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19085239/how-to-convert-gps-coordinates-to-decimal-in-lua) (although problem domain is GPS coordinates instead of date/time)
- [Question about how to do pattern matching in Lua](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426954/split-string-in-lua), several good examples and links to docs